# libGDX antialiasing on desktop seems uneffective

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx, antialiasing

I am working on a desktop game with libGDX. I want to reduce the aliasing, that is very strong.

There is documentation about that. The magic is supposed to happen in the DesktopLauncher class with the line `config.samples = samplingNumber;`

I tried 2, 4, 8 and 16 sampling number. I am unable to see a difference.

Here is my DesktopLauncher class.

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.title = "AA Test";
        config.width = 1280;
        config.height = 720;
        config.samples = 8;
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
}
```

And here is an image showing the difference between no AA and MSAA 16x. The same result is observed for MSAA 2x, 4x and 8x.
[image]

Am I missing something to apply MSAA to my libGDX project ?

Comment: How do you generate this object? Is it an actual "object" or just an image you load?

Comment: It's an image, packed in a Texture Atlas. I also use a linear filter. I actually tried any kind of filter, tried Mipmap... Didn't change anything. But the aliasing problem shouldn't be related to the filter anyway.

Comment: As I read in a JavaGaming forum the AA does not affect images/textures.

Comment: How did you generate your TextureAtlas? Which MipMap filter did you try?

Comment: I used the libGDX texture packer to generate the TextureAtlas. I tried every MipMap filter proposed by the texture packer. On this example I used MipMapLinearNearest, which is the filter I always use in my projects.

Comment: You didn't use the TexturePacker GUI version, did you? That is very buggy.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to this problem.

```
texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

The sampling field, as you experienced, has no effect but setting this filter on the Textures did.

If you are using TextureAtlas then you can do the following to your TextureAtlas object.

```
atlas.getTextures().forEach(t -> t.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear));
```

Comment: I'm using a Texture inside of a Decal and can't get this to work with this

Answer (score 2):

MSAA only affects the edges of polygons, which are not usually visible in a 2D scene because sprites typically do not bleed all the way to their rectangular edges. (Exceptions are opaque rectangular sprites, and shapes drawn with ShapeRenderer.)

Your image quality looks to me like you are not using a mip mapping filter. Load your texture with the `useMipMaps` parameter true, and use a min filter of MipMapLinearLinear or MipMapLinearNearest (the first looks better, costs more). Note: a MipMap filter does nothing if you didn't load your Texture with `useMipMaps` true.

There are AA techniques that do process all pixels of the screen, but they are more expensive than simply using mip mapping and trilinear filtering. One example is FXAA, which is done not with a configuration setting, but by drawing your scene to a frame buffer object, and then drawing the FBO's texture to screen with a special shader.

Comment: Yes I always use MipMap filters. I use MipMapLinearNearest in the above example.
I have to precise that the images are moving. In the screenshot they are rotated. The normal image is completely vertical, but during rotation a lot of aliasing appear. And that's not something MipMap filter can solve.
I guess I'll try to draw my screen in a high resolution FBO, generate a MipMap of the texture and downsize to the screen resolution.

Comment: Texture filters are how texture pixels are sampled and interpolated, so they are absolutely what determines the appearance of pixels within a sprite. Are you absolutely sure your texture has mip maps generated? If you use a mip map filter on a texture that doesn't have all its mip levels loaded, then it still isn't mip mapping. And that will cause aliasing in some cases due to over downsampling. Indulge me and try MipMapLinearLinear.

Comment: By the way, what you described is called SSAA and it is much more expensive than FXAA for a marginal improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Your GPU chip could not support MSAA although then it should support [CSAA](http://developer.nvidia.com/csaa-coverage-sampling-antialiasing).

To make it work you need to replace

```
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

with

```
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | (Gdx.graphics.getBufferFormat().coverageSampling?GL20.GL_COVERAGE_BUFFER_BIT_NV:0));
```

in your `render` method. Then set `config.samples` for Desktop or `config.numSamples` for Android to the desired value.

Read more about LibGDX AA [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2071)

Comment: Yeah that page is one of the pages I consulted to try to solve my MSAA problem. The CSAA didn't work either. I guess that's because, as Andreas Brunnet pointed in a comment on my post, AA does not affect textures.