# How to set up antialiasing in LibGDX 2D mode?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, game-development

I create a videogame using LibGDX.
I want to switch on antialiasing because my game is very pixelarted.
Field:

```
int samples = 0;
```

in the class

```
Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration
```

is not more public and can not be changed via setters.
I have created my own class using the original Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration as template and changed this variable samples but it didn't help.
I have also tried to setBackBufferConfig() using next line:

```
config.setBackBufferConfig(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0, samplesValue);
```

but it doesn't help. I used sampleValues between 1 and 4.
At the beginning of the rendering process I use command:

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | (Gdx.graphics.getBufferFormat().coverageSampling?GL20.GL_COVERAGE_BUFFER_BIT_NV:0));
```

My video card is NVIDIA RTX A2000.

Comment: `setBackBufferConfig` should be the correct thing to do. Could you show a complete example where we can reproduce your problem? You are aware that Antialiasing will only work on the edges of primitives, so if you really have pixel art (which is usually done by texturing), I'm not sure how much AA will help anyway.

Comment: Does it really works only with primitives? I thought it must work also with graphic files rendering.

Comment: Check here you also need to setup the type of filtering you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629909/libgdx-antialiasing-on-desktop-seems-uneffective

Comment: Anti-aliasing only affects the edges of the triangles that OpenGL draws your sprites onto. It will have zero visual impact on typical sprites (ones that have some transparent pixels around the edges). If you want to try to clean up the appearance of the interior pixels of the sprite, it depends on what your source issue is how best to manage it. Could be the type of texture filtering you're using, or you could just have low resolution source sprites. Or if you want to use low-res sprites and upscale them smoothly like some retro game emulators do, you can use a FrameBuffer and shader.

Comment: @Tenfour04 understood, I have tried already filtering - I think it is a good choose for me

Answer (score 0):

In the libGDX discord I've been told that samples only applies anti-aliasing between textures and that I need a shader to apply anti-aliasing within a texture. This is what I've got (code from [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldsSRX)):

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

vec2 saturate(vec2 x) {
    return clamp(x, vec2(0.0), vec2(1.0));
}

vec2 magnify(vec2 uv, vec2 resolution) {
    uv *= resolution;
    return (saturate(fract(uv) / saturate(fwidth(uv))) + floor(uv) - 0.5) / resolution;
}

void main() {
    vec2 resolution = vec2(textureSize(u_texture, 0));
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, magnify(v_texCoords, resolution)) * v_color;
}
```

This shader manipulates the coordinates of the pixel being drawn. It therefore relies on linear interpolation:

```
texture.setFilter(Linear, Linear);
```